# Why does drawImage perform so much faster in Safari than Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawimage, requestanimationframe

I made a little HTML canvas visualizer for fun, and I have noticed that it runs horribly in Chrome, pretty bad in Firefox, but absolutely amazingly in Safari, including iPhone and iPad!

Can anyone explain why?

I think the code should be fairly straightforward, but basically I'm drawing points for mouse (or touch) location(s), then copying the canvas to a temporary canvas using drawImage. From there I clear the display canvas, then copy the temp canvas back (4 times), but applying a few things like rotation, offset, transparency and scale (and playing around with some different globalCompositeOperations), all using drawImage. So in total, drawImage is called 5 times in each loop.

You can view the demo here: http://lakenen.com/vis.html

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

PS. try this on an iPad if you can; it's pretty neat with multi-touch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the performance profiler is pretty much identical in Safari and Chrome you should be able to determine this yourself. Your demo runs fine on both Safari and Chrome on my machine.

Anyway, I can't tell you why drawImage performs worse on Chrome than Safari, only that it does *when an image fails to load and is then drawn.* Otherwise Chrome seems faster on Windows.

[Here's a simple jsperf I made a while ago.](http://jsperf.com/canvas-vs-image/2) It seems to show chrome 19 running twice as fast as safari on my windows 7 machine.

Comment: Yeah, I did use the profiler to narrow it down to drawImage, but this doesn't answer my question: why? Is it something I have to take up with the Chrome team, or am I doing something wrong and Safari just handles it better?

Comment: What kind of a machine are you running? On mine chrome is twice as fast as safari. (And what version of chrome are you using?)

Comment: I am running Chrome 17.0.963.83 on OS X Lion (10.7.3). Chrome gets like 3 fps, whereas Safari is in the 40-50 range (same size browser windows).

Comment: That's odd. At max screen I get 10 on Safari and 60 on Chrome 19. I suppose you should give it a try with the developer version of chrome and see if that changes your figures. Otherwise I'm not really sure why there'd be a discrepancy either way between mac/pc

Comment: Maybe it's something they've fixed in the dev channel. I just tried on Win 7 (Chrome 17) and it's slow there for me as well.

Comment: Very recently they massively sped up some of the low level math operations. Could you try removing the calls to `Math.floor` in `drawImage` and replacing them with: `ctx.drawImage(tmpcanv,(-canvas.width/2) | 0,(-canvas.height/2) | 0);` This is assuming that that call is the one causing the performance problem. It may actually be a different one.

Comment: I just changed it, but seems to be slow still. I tried the dev channel of Chrome, and it's very fast, like you've observed. I'm going to accept your answer, since you led me to the conclusion that it's not my code, and simply a problem with the stable build of Chrome. (PS. I'm just going to assume Firefox is slow simply because it's Firefox.)